# Import SnazzyInfoWindow - Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to import SnazzyInfoWindow into my Angular 5 project but I cannot, and I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

I installed

```
npm install --save snazzy-info-window
```

and then

```
npm install --save @types/snazzy-info-window
```

Then I try to import it

```
import {SnazzyInfoWindow} from 'snazzy-info-window';
```

in my .ts file to be able to use `new SnazzyInfoWindow ({})` but I get the error:

> [ts] The module '".../node_modules/@types/snazzy-info-window/index"' has no 'SnazzyInfoWindow' member exported.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import * as SnazzyInfoWindow from 'snazzy-info-window';

const snazzyWindow = new SnazzyInfoWindow( // options );
```

SnazzyInfoWindow typings expose namespace typings, because the package itself is not written in typescript.

> To describe the shape of libraries not written in TypeScript, we need to declare the API that the library exposes. Because most JavaScript libraries expose only a few top-level objects, namespaces are a good way to represent them.

Read more about [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)